# Interprocess testing

Tags: java, python, testing

I have a Python and a Java application (GUI) that communicate with each other using networking.

What strategy should I use to perform testing, ie. that if I change anything in the Python or Java code, the flow between the two will not be broken in unexpected ways?

Comment: Do you have any testing in place already? E.g. unit tests?

Comment: Are you going to answer Rob or just post a question and then never return?

Comment: I have unit testing of the Python code, but nothing that tests the interprocess communication parts.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an integration test that spools up the two projects socket code in a test harness that performs the communication you want to test. Perhaps you want to do this from Python by starting the python process and then using subprocess to call the Java code link in this example. 
[Python: How can I execute a jar file through a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372592/python-how-can-execute-a-jar-file-through-a-python-script)