# Attempting to execute .jar file using python

Tags: python

I have a .jar file that I need to execute via Python.

My current code is

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['java', '-jar', 'StatsCalc.jar'])
```

I printed out the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ali\Documents\Java Stuff\RedditFitnessCalc\out\artifacts\RedditFitnessCalc_jar\pythonBotScript.py", line 6, in <module>
p = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-jar', 'RedditFitnessCalc.jar'])
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3\lib\subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', 'RedditFitnessCalc.jar']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

When I run it, a window pops up and disappears instantly. It is a java program that has a GUI. I tried running it directly and with a batch file and both work fine.

Comment: Try using `check_output` instead of `call` and post the result.

Comment: I'm assuming you have looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372592/python-how-can-execute-a-jar-file-through-a-python-script and the three other questions it links to.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, I did and I tried all of the solutions but to no avail. Apoligies if it seems like a duplicated but I edited it to include the error.

Comment: @domoarrigato As you said, I have posted the error message, though I cant seem to decipher what is the problem.

Comment: what if you try with `shell=True`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes! It worked and the GUI shows up. If you don't mind posting it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that frequently works is using `shell=True` option on the subprocess, this executes the command as if it was done in a shell (batch file or command prompt)

So using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'StatsCalc.jar'],shell=True)
```

Should work for you, but please read the [Security Considerations section of the subprocess's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) before relying too heavily on this.

Usually the reason it does not work without shell is because it cannot find the command `java` without using the full path, so if you know the full path of the `java` executable that would be preferable to using `shell=True`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['path/to/java', '-jar', 'StatsCalc.jar'])
```

I don't know the exact details on the difference between these two but