# Use java class in Python

Tags: java, python

I am having two classes written in java file. I want to use those java classes in my Python code. I am using IPython Notebook for executing Python code.

I tried making it as .jar file and calling that .jar file in Python as suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372592/python-how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-through-a-python-script). But it shows output on terminal. I want output on same window where I have written code or in some text file.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the output.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/python-how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess) form more details