# launch processing sketch from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame, processing

I'm looking for a way to launch a compiled processing sketch from a function in python. It would just be a button programed with pygame (having a UI is very important.

can you launch an external file from within python?

Comment: why not use `subprocess.Popen` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your compiled jar you can use subprocess as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372651/2360271):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'my-sketch.jar'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to launch an extern command using Python3 (or Python2), you can use one of those methods:

*Example:* i will call the bash function `ls -l` :

**Method1:**

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["ls","-l"]
```

**Method2:**

```
>>> from os import system
>>> system("ls -l")
```

**Bonus:**

If you want to retrieve the output of the extern command you called, use this method:

**Bonus method:**

```
>>> output = subprocess.Popen("ls -l", shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output
```