# Starting Minecraft Server via Discord Bot

Tags: discord.py, minecraft

I just have a question.
Is there some way to program a discord Bot in python,
which is starting a server (On a website (Ploudos)) on a command like !Start-Server or something?
I dont have any code yet, im just interested if there is a way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since ploudus doesnt have a api you can use to start the server. Create selenium script to crawl through the website and start the server, then link to a discord command...

Hope this is what youre after, this method works for automating anything on the web through python.

Comment: Is this simple? I'm not very very very good at python, just didn't find any tutorial on YouTube for that. Could you tell me what a Selenium Script is?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a bat file to start your server, I guess you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code), the following bat code will keep your server open if it crashes:

```
@echo off
cls
title Server name
:StartServer
start /wait java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar server.jar -o true -nogui
echo Server closed/crashed... restarting!
goto StartServer
```

If you don't want it to auro-restart you can just do

```
@echo off
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar server.jar -o true -nogui
```

Note that bat files only work on windows, that way you will have access to the console, anyways, to only execute the server jar, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372592/python-how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-through-a-python-script/7372651).